# Access Saved Searches Command Line

Tags: terminal

I have setup a bunch of saved searched via spotlight.  Is there a way that I can access them from command line?  Ideally I'd like to do an "ls -l [my search name]" but that doesn't really work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the RawQuery key as an argument for mdfind:

```
mdfind "$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'Print RawQuery' test.savedSearch)"
```